# Changing my Keyboard Language in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm automating login and uploading the data for israel based website and i am facing issue as i unable to switch my keyboard from hebrew to english.
when i enter '.' it prints 'ץ'

I am using selenium and tried ActionChains, send_keys by pressing (Alt,Shift) but it seems to have no effect.

I have tried ActionChains, send_keys by pressing (Alt,Shift) but it seems to have no effect.

```
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_textBoxURL').send_keys("http://google")
time.sleep(3)
ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ALT).key_up(Keys.ALT).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
time.sleep(10)
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_textBoxURL').send_keys(".")
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_textBoxURL').send_keys("com")
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_buttonNext1').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Expected to put "http://google.com" instead of "[http://googleץcom](http://google%D7%A5com)"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome I would try set chromium switch `--lang`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-GB")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-GB")

Can you explain what does this line mean?

Comment: It sets chrome language. In this case to british english (en-GB). However I would appreciate if you send link of website where this issue occures

Comment: i want to change my typing language. 
What you have suggested loads the website in English.
My keyboard shifts from hebrew to english using ALT+SHIFT.
I have tried using ActionChains, but it seems like ALT Key is not working.
So, I am looking for a way to change the setting of chromedriver and set typing language as english

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.
I noticed that I had 3 keyboard languages on my computer.
One in English and two different types of Hebrew.
After removing one of the Hebrew languages and making sure it was not the default language it solved the problem.